# Alguien sabe como pasar datos de una clase a una etiqueta <td> es para formar un tabla?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<table id="list" class="bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>  
 </table>
```

Ese esl codigo de la tabla y lo que yo quiero pasar son estos datos de esta clase

```
public ActionResult Index(){
        List<Persona> lista = new List<Persona>();

        Persona per1 = new Persona();
        per1.codigo = 1;
        per1.nombre = "Luthien";
        per1.apepat = "Lopez";
        per1.apemat = "Perez";

        lista.Add(per1);

        Persona per2 = new Persona();
        per2.codigo = 2;
        per2.nombre = "Beren";
        per2.apepat = "Beltran";
        per2.apemat = "Caceres";

        lista.Add(per2);

        Persona per3 = new Persona();
        per3.codigo = 3;
        per3.nombre = "Jorge";
        per3.apepat = "Ramirez";
        per3.apemat = "Castillo";

        lista.Add(per3);

        return View(lista);
}
```

Comment: En realidad previamente la sentencia de html que use es

Comment: que lenguaje ocupas?

Comment: @siosi es C#. Está usando .NET MVC.

Comment: En esta pagina hay un tutorial de como podría hacerlo. Funciona en la versión 2
https://javimarciano.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/mvc3/

Answer (score 0):

Desde la vista, tienes acceso a esa lista a través del objeto Model.

Primero, añade la declaración @model al comienzo de la vista para especificar el tipo de dato de `Model`.

```
@model IEnumerable<TuEspacioDeNombres.Persona>
```

Luego, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
<table id="list" class="bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Persona persona in Model)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>@persona.nombre</td>
            <td>@persona.apemat</td>
            <td>@persona.apepat</td>
        </tr>
     }  
 </table>
```

También deberías añadir

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo, habra algun lugar donde tengan varios ejercicios resueltos como guia aqui yo estoy usando ASP.NET #C MVC 2

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo el modelo *MVC* deberías tener un modelo (clase) con la estructura de datos, en este caso, yo tendría algo así para el modelo.

```
//Clase auxiliar con los datos de la persona//

public class Persona
{
    private String _nombre;
    private String _apellidoMaterno;
    private String _apellidoPaterno;

    public String Nombre
    {
        get{return this._nombre;}
        set{this._nombre = value;}
    }
    public String ApeMaterno
    {
        get{return this._apellidoMaterno;}
        set{this._apellidoMaterno = value;}
    }
    public String ApePaterno
    {
        get{return this._apellidoPaterno;}
        set{this._apellidoPaterno = value;}
    }
    public Persona(String nombre, String apeMaterno, String apePaterno)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.ApeMaterno = apeMaterno;
        this.ApePaterno = apePaterno;
    }
}
//Modelo de datos que pasaremos a la vista para generar la tabla con Razor//

public class ListaPersonasModel
{
    private List<Persona> _listaPersonas = new List<Persona>();

    public List<Persona> lPersonas
    {
        get{return this._listaPersonas;}
        set{this._listaPersonas = value;}
    }
}
//CONTROLADOR//

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ListaPersonasModel lista = new ListaPersonasModel();

    Persona personaUno = new Persona("Luthien", "Lopez","Perez");
    Persona personaDos = new Persona("Beren", "Beltran", "Caceres");
    Persona personaTres = new Persona("Jorge", "Ramirez", "Castillo");

    lista.Add(personaUno);
    lista.Add(personaDos);
    lista.Add(personaTres);

    //Si podemos retornamos una vista y un modelo asociado a dicha vista//
    //En este caso, el modelo era una lista de personas
    //, por lo que pasamos la lista de personas//

    return View("~/Views/NombreVista",lista);
}
```

```html
<table id="list" class="bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var persona in Model)
    {
        <tr>@persona.Nombre</tr>
        <tr>@persona.ApeMaterno</tr>
        <tr>@persona.ApePaterno</tr>
    }
</table>
```

Por último pintamos la vista, en la que tenemos que importar al inicio, **el tipo de datos del modelo**, no el nombre del modelo.

Siempre que trato con *MVC* intento distinguir de los tipos de datos auxiliares (clase `persona` en este caso) del modelo que le voy a pasar a la vista, por que una vista puede llegar a ser mucho más compleja, y aunque es más trabajoso, también intento distinguir entre miembros privados y propiedades, para no tocar nada privado de las clases desde la vista.